# Jquery accordion remove line break

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to remove the line break so that each picture is right next to each other. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/5dkLu/

Comment: something like [this...](http://jsfiddle.net/5dkLu/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
.accordion a {
     display: inline-block; /* used inline-block instead of block*/
     color: black;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5dkLu/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using just a few lines of code:

```
.accordion dd a {
    float: left;
}

.accordion dd {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow: hidden; //Added this line.
}
```

While this may solve your problem, I'd highly suggest you take a look at the formatting of your code.  I would almost never suggest floating `a` tags.  Perhaps you could put these in an unordered list and make each `a` tag contained within an `li` tag.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I was using an older version of jquery-ui.js (< 1.90). When I switched to jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.js, it all worked fine.

Actually, changing the icon display attribute to inline-block is a very lousy solution. If you compare the position of the icon and the text you will see that it's different then what it was supposed to be.